# Where can I put the computer so I don't wake up the roommate

Tags: the-sims-3

I'm going to start a game with `computer whiz` roommates.  I was thinking about putting a computer in each bedroom, but am concerned about the potential for noise to interfere with sleep.

```
B = Bed
C = Computer Desk
D = Door

|---|---|
|B C|B C|
|B C|B C|
|B  |B  |
|-D-|-D-|
```

I'm worried that the right room's bed is only separated from a loud noise source by one wall and no squares.

Will that noise wake up the roommate?  How far (squares, walls, what?) should I put a computer from a bed to ensure there's no sleep interruptions?

Comment: Get head phones...it will solve all your problems.

Comment: When I tested this, I found that noise from the left desk does not wake the right-side bed.  However, the desks in this arrangement make the bed un-reachable as the chair blocks the entry point.  Instead, placing the desks against the wall opposite the door works(nightstand position).

Comment: I didn't at first realize this was in a game, and couldn't figure out why it hadn't been closed...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as you don't upgrade your house with speakers, noisesome objects are confined to the room they are in.

This means every wall in the Sims 3 is effectively soundproof.

Comment: Thanks, tested: Not even extreme computer gaming in the next room can penetrate that wall.